# TS2322 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: typescript

Good day.
Please clarify why this is happening? When using the simplest TypeScript code structure, I get an error:

```
      TS2322: Type '() => { scale: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CreateBreakpoints'.
  Call signature return types '{ scale: string; }' and 'Breakpoints<T>' are incompatible.
    The types of 'scale' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
```

Code:

```
export interface Breakpoints<T> {
  scale: T,
}

export interface CreateBreakpoints {
  <T = string>(): Breakpoints<T>;
}

const createBreakpoints: CreateBreakpoints = () => {
  return {
    scale: "",
  };
};
```

[image]

Comment: Your function can be called as `createBreakpoints<number>()`, thus the implementation is not going to match.

Comment: Please be sure to [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+could+be+instantiated+with) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).